# How to write a getter for a type in C++ without undefining the type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, shared-ptr, getter

I have a collection of objects that implement an interface, and I want to have getters on it to get the individual implementations only in C++. In Java, I would do this:

```java
interface IFooBar { }
class Foo implements IFooBar { }
class Bar implements IFooBar { }

class Container extends HashSet<IFooBar> {

    public Container() { }
    public Container(Collection<? extends IFooBar> c) { super(c); }

    Foo getFoo() {
        return getFoos().iterator().next();
    }

    Set<Foo> getFoos() {
        HashSet<Foo> result = new HashSet<>();
        for(IFooBar item:this) if (item instanceof Foo) result.add((Foo) item);
        return result;
    }

    Bar getBar() { /* ... same ... */ }

    Set<Bar> getBars() { /* ... same ... */ }
}
```

Now I tried to do the same in C++. For project requirement, I have to use `shared_ptr<>` of my objects. This is how far I came:

```
class IFooBar { }
class CFoo : IFooBar { }
class CBar : IFooBar { }

class CContainer {
public:
    CContainer();
    CContainer(std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<IFooBar>> cPrivData);

    const std::shared_ptr<CFoo> CFoo();
    std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<CFoo>> CFoos();
                                   /* ^^^^ : Function CContainer::CFoo is not a type name */
    const std::shared_ptr<CBar> CBar();
    std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<CBar>> CBars();

private:
    std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<IObject>> m_cPrivData;
};
```

Obviously this does not work, I cannot give the getter the name it should have (as I think). I get the indicated error. The function seems to undefine the type name. Now I wonder **which would be an intuitively usable implementation of what I gave als Java example in C++?** Or, what would be the recommended name for the getter? I learned that in C++ the getter is named without leading ‘get’, and function names start uppercase. I want the getter to reflect what class type it returns.

Perhaps I should go a completely other way? Instead of function `CFoo()`, could I define an assignment constructor, if so, how? Do I have to overload `shared_ptr<>` to do so? If so, how? Something like this was my idea:

```
class CSharedFooBarPointer : std::shared_pointer<IFooBar> {
public:
    shared_ptr<Foo> operator=(std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<IFooBar>>& cContainer);
    shared_ptr<Bar> operator=(std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<IFooBar>>& cContainer);
}
```

(Maybe I think too Java’ish here, but I am quite new to C++.) Perhaps this approach is bad because maybe I cannot use it in-line. Or can I? From the Java example above, I want to be able to do things like `container.getFoo().doSomethingFooSpecific();`. In C++, what would I have to use for syntax? Is there something like `((CFoo)cContainer).DoSomethingFooSpecific();`? I don’t want to need to assign a variable if I only use it once, if possible.

Comment: What is `IObject`?

Comment: Also, C++ doesn't really have a universal code convention that everyone follows, leading the method name with `Get` is something I've seen a lot.

Comment: Name conflict can be solved by adding '::'. Like ```const std::shared_ptr<::CFoo> CFoo();```

Comment: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74fe90c5e6f7e1bc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>*Note: the code in this answer is untested and may contain typos.*</sub>

> I learned that in C++ the getter is named without leading ‘get’, and function names start uppercase.

Not to my knowledge. But as mentioned by [Gill Bates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041136/how-to-write-a-getter-for-a-type-in-c-without-undefining-the-type#comment75108421_44041136), C++ doesn't have a centralized style guide, so just pick a code style and stick to it. I personally never see functions starting with capitals outside of ol' MFC and WINAPI -- you might be thinking of C# on that one. Ditto for the `C` class prefix.

In any case, name collisions can be resolved with the [scope resolution operator `::`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup):

```
class CContainer {
    // ...
    const std::shared_ptr<CFoo> CFoo();
    std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<::CFoo>> CFoos();
    //     CFoo from the global scope ^^
    // ...
};
```

---

Getting one step ahead about implementing the functions:
To determine the dynamic type of an object at runtime, you need [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), or in your case the [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) helper function.

```
std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<::CFoo>> CContainer::CFoos() {
    std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<::CFoo>> result;

    for(auto const &objPtr : m_cPrivData)
        if(auto fooPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<::CFoo>(objPtr))
            result.push_back(std::move(fooPtr));

    return result;
}
```

However, `dynamic_cast` requires the object's type to be polymorphic, which means that `IFooBar` needs to have at least one virtual member function. If no adequate function is present, a common choice is to make the destructor virtual:

```
struct IFooBar {
    virtual ~IFooBar() = default;
};
```

---

Note on efficiency:
Just like `instanceof` in Java, `dynamic_cast` is a pretty expensive operation. If the main use case of this class is to filter that list of `CFoo`s and `CBars`, you probably want to do this *once* in the constructor, and store them in separate containers:

```
class CContainer {
public:
    CContainer(std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<IFooBar>> cPrivData) {
        for(auto const &objPtr : cPrivData)
            if(auto fooPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<::CFoo>(objPtr))
                _foos.push_back(std::move(fooPtr));
            else if(auto barPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<::CBar>(objPtr))
                _bars.push_back(std::move(barPtr));
    }

private:
    std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<::CFoo>> _foos;
    std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<::CBar>> _bars;
};
```